# error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed in file_get_contents

Tags: php, openssl

When using `file_get_contents()` to access an HTTPS URL, I get the following in my logs:

```
[21-Jun-2021 10:21:23 Australia/Sydney] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed in C:\path\to\script.php on line 174
[21-Jun-2021 10:21:23 Australia/Sydney] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(): Failed to enable crypto in C:\path\to\script.php on line 174
[21-Jun-2021 10:21:23 Australia/Sydney] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(https://...): failed to open stream: operation failed in C:\path\to\script.php on line 174
```

The website loads just fine in my browser.  I have also downloaded cURL's CA certificates and told PHP where to find them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I had an incomplete certificate in my Apache configuration. I only had the certificate itself, not also its intermediate. The site worked fine in the browser, but failed when I tried to do it in PHP. The web firewall at work also refused to let me through to similarly configured websites for the same reason. Replacing it with a certificate file that included its intermediary solved this issue.

To check your site, go to https://whatsmychaincert.com and enter your website domain. If your site doesn't have its intermediary, it'll supply you with a certificate file complete with the relevant intermediary for you to install.

[image: if your certificate is misconfigured...]

If the website in question is internal, you can paste the certificate into the second form and it'll do the same:

[image: if you paste your certificate]

No need to get the root certificate, since the client will already have that.