# Laravel app email is not working Unable to connect with STARTTLS:

Tags: laravel

Unable to connect with STARTTLS: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed

[image]

Comment: its working in my dev ubuntu server and not working in live server

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57358047/openssl-error-messages-error1416f086ssl-routinestls-process-server-certifica, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46511717/how-to-fix-ssl-certificate-verification-failure, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32019623/openssl-error-messages-error14090086ssl-routinesssl3-get-server-certificate, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53351117/php-composer-https-error-1416f086-certificate-verifying-failed, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68062111/error1416f086ssl-routinestls-process-server-certificatecertificate-verify-fa, ...

Answer (score -1):

This error suggests that the certificate provided by the server you are trying to connect to cannot be verified. There are a few common reasons for this error:

**Expired or Invalid SSL Certificate:** The server's SSL certificate might be expired, self-signed, or issued by an untrusted certificate authority.

**Missing CA Certificates:** The client (your application) may not have the necessary root CA certificates to verify the server's certificate.

**Hostname Mismatch:** The hostname you are connecting to doesn't match the one in the server's certificate.

Comment: this mail is working in my development server..but not working in my live server

Comment: change your server hostname to your local server name